# Rails - How can I save a field value (that uses a record's ID) though a callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, hash, md5

I want to create a hash that combines the creating user's user_id + the record's ID to make a MD5 hash, but only on record creation. (Reasons are long-winded but this extracts it).

I am trying:

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base  

  after_create :hash_this

  private

  def hash_this
    self.info_md5_hashed = (id.to_str + creator_user_id).my_MD5_hash_method
  end

end
```

How can I make sure that the `info_md5_hashed` field actually gets saved to the database?

If I use `before_create` I would assume that the ID is not yet available? :(
If I use `after_create` I would assume that the ID is now available
 - but do I need to do another save somehow to store the newly calculated info_md5_hashed field value?

Comment: Can you post more specific information about the broader problem you're trying to solve?  I can update my answer if I have more of an understanding about why you need this.  Generating an immutable ID attached to the user on create (that isn't the primary key) is another alternative... e.g. a UUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will have to save the record twice, since ID generation happens in the database.  The only way around that is to pre-sequence an ID, but there's almost certainly no point and you should just accept that you will have to save the record twice ;)

Just call the second save from inside your `after_create` hook- it's ok to do this (i.e. will not be a looping recurrence issue) because the second save won't re-trigger that hook again ;)

n.b. You could always base the hash on something you know to be unique, such as the username or email, if you want to avoid a double-save.

Comment: ok good, do I put that in the controller and basically call BlogPost.new followed by BlogPost.save ?  Nervous about that firing off validations though.  I can I can do  `, :validate => false` but if I also have the validations as database constraints (best practice) will I have an issue or will that depend on if I use `save` or `save!`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  What are you referring to putting in the controller?  You can generate an ID before_create, if you really must (lock a dedicated sequences table in the DB, select its highest ID, increment that number, write it back to the table and unlock the table), but I'd honestly just avoid trying to optimize away the second save, if your concern is performance.

Comment: Thanks, no issue for performance and doing two saves is fine.  Just trying to make sure I know where to put the code.  Controllers instantiate the object with .new but the callbacks are in the model I wasn't clear exactly on the code / location for the two saves.

Comment: Just call the second save from inside your after_create hook.  That's fine, since the second save won't trigger that hook ;)

Comment: Awesome. Accepted. Any preference on `save` vs `save!` ?

Comment: also added to answer for others :)

Comment: it [might] be nice (i.e. a railsy convention thing) if any after_create's that modify a model's attr it gets saved by default and one just sets true or false from the :after_create as to whether that gets done.  But may not.  Or maybe default is no action, but there is an option for a 're-save'.

Comment: You're welcome.  There's definitely no built-in way to have that automatic behaviour, and it would probably be undesirable most of the time ;)  You just need to understand the order in which things happen.